# How do access Bamboo project and global variables

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, bamboo

I've been using Bamboo for 3 weeks and I'm busy writing a plugin to display build results. One of the things I need to do is generate a pick up location from the global and project variables I've setup but I can't seem to find a way of doing this via a plugin.

I've tried looking at the Atlassian developer forum but I've found nothing useful.

Does anyone have any experience with Bamboo plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes, I had to root around to find this one out too. It's on their wiki, explained in detail:

- http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Defining+Global+Variables
- http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Using+Global%2C+Plan+or+Build-specific+Variables

You have to pass the global variables into your task configured for the script or plugin.

Comment: Okay so its accessible when you implement the TaskType interface but it doesn't seem possible from if you trying to create a Webpanel plugin.